# Postgres Double Quotes No Escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, full-text-search

I have this model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      rank = <<-RANK
        ts_rank(to_tsvector(title), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)})) +
        ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)}))
      RANK
      where("to_tsvector('english', title) @@ :q or
        to_tsvector('english', content) @@ :q", q: sanitize(query)).order("#{rank} desc")
    else
      scoped
    end 
  end 

end
```

and I have this method call

```
Post.text_search("Where is the safest place")
```

Question: why is it that it that the query does not escape the double quotes when being called in SQL? As shown here:

```
  Post Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (to_tsvector('english', title) @@ '''Where is the safest place''' or
 to_tsvector('english', content) @@ '''Where is the safest place''') ORDER BY ts_rank(to_tsvector(title), plainto_tsquery('Where is the safest place')) +
 ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), plainto_tsquery('Where is the safest place'))
```

Comment: rails `where` method will auto sanitize query parameters, the `order` method will not, you need to sanitize that yourself, but leave sanitize off of the where parameters

Answer (score 1):

Just wrapped the ":q" binding in "plainto_tsquery()"

```
where("to_tsvector('english', title) @@ :q or
        to_tsvector('english', content) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q)", q: query).order("#{rank} desc")
```